# System of differential equations, pure imaginary eigenvalues, show that the trajectory is an ellipse.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am stuck at the last part of a proof.

When you have the system of equations:

$x'=Ax$

$$
        A=\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Show that when you have purely imaginary eigenvalues the trajectories in the phase plane x1 and x2 is an ellipse.

**First step**

When the eigenvalues are purely imaginary $a_{11}+a_{22} =0$ and $a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}>0$

this was easy to proof.

**Second step**

The trajectories can be written as the following expression:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{a_{21}x+a_{22}y}{a_{11}x+a_{12}y}$

Now this expression is an exact differential equation when $a_{22}=-a_{11}$
This was shown in the first step. So I could just fill this in  and this equation is exact. So now I solved it giving the next equation:

$a_{21}x^2+2a_{22}xy-a_{12}y^2 = constant$

Now the last step is to show that this equation is an ellipse when the eigenvalues are purely imaginary. For some reason, I can't find a proof for this. I know the main form of an ellipse in any direction orientated is:

$Ax^2-Bxy+Cy^2 = constant$

Now, how can I proof that given that the eigenvalues of the matrix we started with are purely imaginary, we get an ellipse here ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this site http://www.mathamazement.com/Lessons/Pre-Calculus/09_Conic-Sections-and-Analytic-Geometry/rotation-of-axes.html

Essentially, the general equation for any conic section is
\begin{equation*}
Ax^{2} + Bxy + Cy^{2} + Dx + Ey + F = 0
\end{equation*}
for some real numbers $A,B,C,D,E,F$. However, not all choices of coefficients will yield a conic section, and from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section we have that the equation above is an ellipse precisely when the discriminant $B^{2} - 4AC < 0$. Proving this is probably fairly straightforward, albeit tedious. In the first link, the author proves that the discriminant is invariant under rotation of coordinates.

In this problem you have, we have that
\begin{equation*}
\det(\lambda I - A)= \lambda^{2} - \mathrm{trace}(A) \lambda + \det(A),
\end{equation*}
and so in order to have purely imaginary coefficients, we need $\mathrm{trace}(A) = 0$ and $\det(A) = a_{22}a_{11} - a_{12}a_{21} > 0$.

From your equation for the trajectories:
\begin{equation*}
a_{21}x^{2} + 2a_{22}xy - a_{12}y^{2} = constant,
\end{equation*}
we see that the discriminant is
\begin{equation*}
(2a_{22})^{2} - 4a_{21}(-a_{12}) = 4a_{22}^{2} + 4a_{12}a_{21} = -4a_{22}a_{11} + 4a_{12}a_{22} = -4\det(A).
\end{equation*}
Since $\det(A) > 0$, the discriminant is negative, and hence the curve is an ellipse.

Comment: Thank you, but in my course text of algebra, an ellipse was not defined with the D,E and F. So I wasn't paying attention to that.