# What does a purely imaginary eigen value really tell us about dynamical system

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

So I know that in regard to dynamical systems,

if we compute our Jacobian matrix, then to use that to assess stability , we need $\lambda$ to be a hyperbolic fixed point , ie Re($\lambda$) $\neq 0$

What can we say when the eigen values are purely imaginary?

I was told something along the lines of , the stability will look like an ellipse, but I am not sure why or how.

Comment: Your question actually requires a lot of background so you might be best off reading about it yourself. If $\Re(\lambda) = 0$ then you have a non-hyperbolic critical point and hence you have a [centre manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_manifold). Hopefully that gets you started.

Comment: In a linear system, a purely imaginary eigenvalue gives stability but not asymptotic stability, so that you just oscillate around the equilibrium point forever if you start sufficiently close to it. In nonlinear systems this is no longer preserved and a variety of things can happen. Notably, the linear behavior is preserved for Hamiltonian systems.

Comment: @Mattos  thankyou. so by ellipse is that just a simplified version of saying centre manifold"

Comment: @Quality Not really, no. The behavior of the trajectory along the center manifold is more complicated than on the unstable manifold or the stable manifold.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105602/system-of-differential-equations-pure-imaginary-eigenvalues-show-that-the-traj?rq=1) might also be useful to show you _why_ purely imaginary eigenvalues gives an ellipse.

Comment: @Ian  Thanks, I have not learnt of Hamiltonian systems yet, do you know where I could see some info of this in the context we are talking about?